# Opening A Local File / Folder From Within The Browser

Tags: php

I know this has been asked several times, but I am just wondering if there is any work arounds if apache etc is running on the same pc.

Basically I am trying to build an intranet customer manager, it runs locally on the pc of a shop, I am building it in php and the shop basically inputs the customer details and this is saved in the local mysql database. What they also would like is the ability to add photos / diagrams to each of the customer files.

When a new customer is created I have got php to create a directory for them on the computer. When the shop opens the customer file, it lists all the customer details and also lists all the files inside the customers directory that the shop has added.

I want to add a link on the customer page so that the shop can click on it and it will open the directory in windows exporer, but I seem to have hit a brick wall as all of the modern browsers seem to stop you opening a file such as >>
file:///C:/server2go/server2go/htdocs/customermgr/customer-files/28734f6d045f8a5a93.18936710CustomerTemplateDemo2010.zip

Is there ANY workarounds for this at all ?, im not sure if you can use visual basic with php at all to open it ?, or any kind of work around at all, so that I can either open the file or directory from the customers page ?.

Answer (score 0):

Well, on your example, the file is in HTDOCS, so it should be accessible with HTTP ;)

Comment: Hi, It is, but the problem is saving it, if the shop opens the uploaded file for editing , they then have to work out what folder to save it in, were as if I could just open the folder they could open the doc then hit save and it would save it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround, and this it is entirely intentional that this should be impossible. To allow it would be a massive security weakness.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones answers, I have decided to link to the files via http instead, and also echo the customer id at the top of each customer record page, then put a shortcut on the desktop to the customer folders. The shop can then look at the ID at the top of the record and open the corresponding folder manually.